# cURL not loading on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, installation, curl

I have come across a very weird problem.
My cURL PHP extension doesn't seem to be running.

I have installed cURL using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

And everything runs fine in the installation process, it restarts apache2 without any errors.

I checked the php.ini file and added a line at the end:

```
extension=php_curl.so
```

And it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: It just simply doesn't load up when starting apache. I have tried everything I know of.

Comment: Which `php.ini` file did you edit?

Comment: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: That is the file that gets listed as main one in phpinfo()